# Can't run go script

Tags: go

I have a file to which I've written the go run header, but the file isn't executing.

This site shows an example that doesn't work for me. https://coderwall.com/p/_kdjzq/go-run-run-go-as-a-script-language

./scripts/test.go

```
//usr/bin/env go run "$0" "$@"; exit

package scripts

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

I am trying to invoke it like this:

```
chmod +x ./scripts/test.go
./scripts/test.go

Failed to execute process './scripts/test.go'. Reason:
exec: Exec format error
The file './scripts/test.go' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.
```

Comment: How exactly are you expecting this to work? You can’t just take any language source code and run it like a script. You can pass something like this to a shell, but why? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707178/whats-the-appropriate-go-shebang-line

Comment: Go must be compiled before you can execute it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the appropriate Go shebang line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707178/whats-the-appropriate-go-shebang-line)

Answer (score 3):

A Go file cannot be an executable file, by definition [1].

Please, do not try to treat it as such. Just run `go install` [2], then you can
run the resultant program from any path.

1. [Should I use a Shebang with Bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165808)
2. https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: What do I do after go install?

Answer (score 0):

Go is a compiled language, not an interpreted one. To run a go file properly, first compile it via `go build <go file>`. If you want to run go as an interpreted language, you can use a go interpreter called [yaegi](https://github.com/traefik/yaegi).