# Does a C source-code/script/program uses a shebang-like command?

Tags: c, shebang, magic-numbers

might be a stupid question but I'll try anyway:

when you turn a shell-script into an executable, it uses the shebang to knows which interpreter to use when you run it. Does a C code/script/program uses/has something similar?

are there any magic numbers in the beginning of an executable C-program?

Comment: It is a plain text file almost always saved with `.c` extension.

Comment: @MohitJain I'm talking about the executable, not the c script (or is there is some hidden line in the c-script?)

Comment: It is not script. For ABI detail please read: [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)

Comment: Well, there is `#!/usr/bin/tcc -run`…

Comment: see also [Is there an interpreter for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c) and [Have you used any of the C++ interpreters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers) and [Run C or C++ file as a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482348/run-c-or-c-file-as-a-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

C program executables (and all compiled languages) start with the "magic" characters `0x7f` `E` `L` `F`. The Linux kernel recognises this in the same way as it recognises shebang scripts, except that it then triggers the ELF loader, not the script interpreter.

It's not *actually* shebang, but it's analogous.

Comment: Unix C program executables start with 7f E L F. Windows C programs start with MZ

Answer (score 2):

The *shebang* is used by the *shell*<sup>*</sup> to recognize a script that needs an executable program to be started beforehand, to which the script will be given as parameter.

E.g. script named "myscript.pl", having executable access rights

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# perl script
```

The shell sees the `#!` and starts a process like this:

```
/usr/bin/perl myscript.pl
```

Compiled C programs are directly executable, and their "magic number" is *not* to say it is/was a C program. The magic number means it is a particular executable that fits the OS, and the executable machine code (starting at a given address) will be then directly executed by the/a processor.

<sup>*</sup>*Historically, the shell was in charge of detecting the shebang. Nowadays the kernel does it directly* (See comments below).

Comment: The point of the shebang line is that the kernel *does* recognize it. Shells don't need to parse it themselves

Comment: Historically [it was the shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#History) but nowadays it's the kernel, indeed.

Comment: two good answers, that actually complete each other. I had to choose one... :-) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After some google-ing, I think I understand the following (though i'm not 100% sure):

Some programming languages such as bash, python, php and other languages uses an interpreter - and so could require a shebang. The interpreter, unlike the compiler, translates the program-code to machine-language every time it is called.

C does not uses an interpreter, but only a compiler - which translates the code only once to an executable / object-file.

So the answer is - NO - c-code does not need a shebang.

Answer (score 0):

The term "magic number" is actually applies better to compiled programs than scripts. There were already magic numbers to identify executable files before the shebang was invented.

A magic number is any short byte sequence at a fixed offset (usually the beginning of a file) that is intended to enable programs to quickly decide what format the file is in. There's an ELF magic number, a PNG magic number, a gzip magic number...

The shebang is sort of an *imitation* of the magic number principle.

Also, in ELF there *is* a thing called the ELF interpreter, which the kernel must be aware of, which is analogous to a script interpreter. If an ELF executable has an interpreter, the kernel starts the program at the interpreter's entry point instead of the main executable's entry point. Every dynamically linked program uses this feature. The dynamic linker is the ELF interpreter.