# How to rotate a 2-D array upwards?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to shift the contents of a 2d array up. I have following 2d 4*4 array

> 3 7 6 5
> 5 8 2 4
> 9 7 3 1
> 8 2 1 0

I am trying to move up every row, and I want to get the following array:

> 5 8 2 4
> 9 7 3 1
> 8 2 1 0
> 3 7 6 5

Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int noCols = 4;

void cycleup(int arr[4][4])
{
    int tmp = 0;

    for (int r2 = 0; r2 < 4; r2++)
    {
        tmp = arr[3][0];
        for (int c = 3; c >= 1; c--)
        {
            arr[c][r2] = arr[c - 1][r2];
        }
        arr[0][r2] = tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int arcg[4][4] = {{3, 7, 6, 5}, {5, 8, 2, 4}, {9, 7, 3, 1}, {8, 2, 1, 0}};

    cycleup(arcg);
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; ++col)
            cout << "\t" << arcg[row][col];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

However, I couldn't get my desired output. Can you help me?

Comment: Call that a rotation rather than a shift.

Comment: Please describe in what way you "couldn't get your desired output".

Comment: My `cycleup()` function is as simple as this: `array2d->i_start = (array2d->i_start + 1) % NUM_ROWS;`. [Check it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76210820/4561887) It's an efficient ring buffer approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it seems that you confused "row" and "column". Then you need to gives special treatment to the first row.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int noCols = 4;

void cycleup(int arr[4][4]) {
    int tmp = 0;
    // backup first line
    int first[4];
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c) {
        first[c] = arr[0][c];
    }
    // move up each line but the first
    for (int r2 = 1; r2 < 4; r2++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c) {
            arr[r2 - 1][c] = arr[r2][c];
        }
    }
    // copy backed-up line into the last row
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; ++c) {
        arr[3][c] = first[c];
    }
}

int main() {
    int arcg[4][4] = {{3, 7, 6, 5}, {5, 8, 2, 4}, {9, 7, 3, 1}, {8, 2, 1, 0}};

    cycleup(arcg);
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; ++col) cout << "\t" << arcg[row][col];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7hGY1PsEP)

Comment: There is no need to process row by row, you can keep the OP's order.

Comment: Iterating in the natural order may give better performance if the array is large.

Comment: This works. But, rotating the array by [not copying nor moving any data within the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76210820/4561887) gives better performance. The time complexity of copying and rewriting the array to rotate it is equal to O(n), where `n` is the number of rows in this case. The time complexity of my approach is a very short O(1), regardless of how big the array is or how many rows it has.

Answer (score 3):

For many use cases, you can accomplish the equivalent in O(1) by shifting your indices instead of your data.

- Keep track of `row_shift` and `col_shift`, initially both zero.
- When setting or retrieving data for (row, col), internally you'll update (row, col) to `((row + row_shift) % num_rows`, `(col + col_shift) % num_cols)`
- When shifting the grid, instead shift the `row_shift` or `col_shift` variables.

Comment: Upvoted. For anyone wondering, updating the indices rather than copying and rotating all of the data is *waaay* more efficient, and is called a "ring buffer" or "circular buffer". It's a common architectural style for an efficient FIFO buffer, especially in embedded systems.

Comment: I demonstrate this fully in code in my [2D array ring buffer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76210820/4561887) I just added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) function as:

```
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  int arcg[4][4] = { { 3, 7, 6, 5 }, { 5, 8, 2, 4 }, { 9, 7, 3, 1 }, { 8, 2, 1, 0 } };

  std::rotate(arcg[0], arcg[1], arcg[4]);

  for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; ++col)
      cout << "\t" << arcg[row][col];
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Here's an example that moves the second and third rows to the end:

```
  std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 4> a { { { 3, 7, 6, 5 }, { 5, 8, 2, 4 }, { 9, 7, 3, 1 }, { 8, 2, 1, 0 } } };

  auto first_row       = 1;
  auto last_row        = 2;
  auto destination_row = 3;

  auto f   = a.begin() + first_row;
  auto f_n = a.begin() + last_row + 1;
  auto l   = a.begin() + destination_row + 1;

  std::rotate(f, f_n, l);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudocode:**

- for every column

  - save the top element
  - for every row but the first

    - copy the element (row, column) up
  - copy the saved element to the bottom row

Answer (score 0):

### Efficiently rotating a 2D array up by treating it as a "ring buffer" or "circular buffer"

Let's not copy or move the data in the 2D array. That's not efficient. Instead, let's rotate this 2D array by moving an `i_start` row index around, treating the whole thing like a ["ring buffer" or "circular buffer"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), which is a common architectural style for an efficient FIFO buffer, especially in embedded systems.

@Dave mentions this concept [in his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76209926/4561887).

The time complexity of copying and/or rewriting the array to rotate it is equal to O(n), where `n` is the number of rows in this case. The time complexity of my approach below is a very short O(1), regardless of how big the array is or how many rows it has, since all we are doing to "rotate" it up is `array2d->i_start = (array2d->i_start + 1) % NUM_ROWS;`, which is *very* efficient!

Here is a full demonstration of this concept, using C-style arrays in C++. Note that if you just got rid of the `= 0;` part of the struct below, and also `typedef`ed it (my preference) *or* added the word `struct` in a few more places where needed, this would also be a perfectly-valid C program.

[cpp/ring_buffer_rotate_2d_array_up.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/ring_buffer_rotate_2d_array_up.cpp) from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```cpp
///usr/bin/env ccache g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu++17 "$0" -o /tmp/a && /tmp/a "$@"; exit
// For the line just above, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491834/4561887

// C++ (incl. C) includes
#include <cstdio>   // For `printf()`
#include <iostream>  // For `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::endl`, etc.

// Get the number of elements in any C array
// - from my repo here:
//   https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/utilities.h#L42
#define ARRAY_LEN(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0]))

/// Definitions: `rows` = "rows"; `cols` = "columns"

/// Get number of rows in a 2D array
#define NUM_ROWS(array_2d) ARRAY_LEN(array_2d)
/// Get number of columns in a 2D array
#define NUM_COLS(array_2d) ARRAY_LEN((array_2d)[0])


struct Array2d
{
    // the actual C-style 2D array of data
    int array[4][4];
    // the starting index for the array, which represents the "first row"
    size_t i_start = 0;
};

// Print the 2D array.
// - Note: pass by const reference since we won't change the array while
//   printing.
void array2d_print(const Array2d& array2d)
{
    const size_t NUM_ROWS = NUM_ROWS(array2d.array);
    const size_t NUM_COLS = NUM_COLS(array2d.array);

    size_t i_row = array2d.i_start;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (size_t i_col = 0; i_col < NUM_COLS; i_col++)
        {
            printf("%3i", (array2d.array)[i_row][i_col]);
            if (i_col < NUM_COLS - 1)
            {
                printf(",");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }

        // increment our "ring-buffer-style" row index
        i_row = (i_row + 1) % NUM_ROWS;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Rotate the 2D array up.
// - Note: pass by ptr since we **will** change the array (the `i_start` index
//   in this case), and we want this fact to be obvious when the user calls
//   this function.
void array2d_rotateup(Array2d* array2d)
{
    const size_t NUM_ROWS = NUM_ROWS(array2d->array);
    // Note: since the `i_start` index is an **unsigned** integer `size_t` type,
    // this approach works perfectly fine even if the integer value overflows
    // upward and rolls over, so there is never a need to check for overflow.
    // This works fine and is well-defined behavior as-is. **Signed** integers,
    // however, have technically **undefined** behavior during overflow and
    // underflow.
    array2d->i_start = (array2d->i_start + 1) % NUM_ROWS;
}

int main()
{
    Array2d array2d =
    {
        .array =
        {
            {1,   2,  3,  4},
            {5,   6,  7,  8},
            {9,  10, 11, 12},
            {13, 14, 15, 16},
        }
    };

    // print the starting array
    array2d_print(array2d);

    // now rotate and print the array NUM_ROWS times
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS(array2d.array); i++)
    {
        array2d_rotateup(&array2d);
        array2d_print(array2d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Run command and output:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ cpp/ring_buffer_rotate_2d_array_up.cpp
  1,  2,  3,  4
  5,  6,  7,  8
  9, 10, 11, 12
 13, 14, 15, 16

  5,  6,  7,  8
  9, 10, 11, 12
 13, 14, 15, 16
  1,  2,  3,  4

  9, 10, 11, 12
 13, 14, 15, 16
  1,  2,  3,  4
  5,  6,  7,  8

 13, 14, 15, 16
  1,  2,  3,  4
  5,  6,  7,  8
  9, 10, 11, 12

  1,  2,  3,  4
  5,  6,  7,  8
  9, 10, 11, 12
 13, 14, 15, 16
```

### References

1. [my answer on 2D arrays] [How to use multidimensional (ex: 2D) arrays, and pointers to them, as function parameters in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814330/4561887)

### See also

1. For more on ring (circular) buffers, including a full demo/library module, see my [containers_ring_buffer_FIFO.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/containers_ring_buffer_FIFO.c) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.